# error while extracting body part from JSON in php

Tags: php, json, decode

I am creating http_client object and making a GET request. Below is my code.

```
$httpc = new HTTP_CLIENT();
$httpc->get("$endpointUrl?operation=getchallenge&username=$userName");
$response = $httpc->currentResponse();
print_r($response);
output: Array ( [url] => http://localhost:8888//webservice.php?operation=getchallenge&username=admin [code] => 200 [headers] => Array ( [date] => Thu, 27 Sep 2012 07:30:17 GMT [server] => Apache/2.0.52 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6 [x-powered-by] => PHP/5.2.6 [expires] => Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT [cache-control] => no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 [pragma] => no-cache [content-length] => 102 [connection] => close [content-type] => application/json ) [body] => ï»¿{"success":true,"result":{"token":"50640089780c4","serverTime":1348731017,"expireTime":1348731317}} )

jsonResponse = Zend_JSON::decode($response['body']);
```

I tried to extract "body" part from this Array, but value i get is blank. Help me if you can.

Note : You can see the output having JUNK value at starting of [body] part.

Comment: `$endpointUrl` is your script or an API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that is an API and they clearly have some BOM characters your should exatrct them and decode:

```
$jsonResponse = Zend_JSON::decode(substr($response['body'], 6));
```

Comment: @mihailorga,  I didnt understand ..can you explain in brief

Comment: Their response contains some [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) characters that are displaying when you get response. You remove them manually or ask them to solve their problem.

Comment: @mihailorga I tried your solution given above. still jsonResponse is empty

Comment: and yaah,,, one correction.Substring index should be 3 instead of 6

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var_dump(Zend_Json_Decoder::decode($data, Zend_Json::TYPE_ARRAY));
```